# create a loop inside a loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv

i am trying to use this program to get a list (phi0ex) of 211 arrays each array contains 251*251 elements 
all what i get is a list of arrays of 251 elements, please help

```
data=loadtxt('data.csv',delimiter=',')
data1=data.transpose()
ngrains=loadtxt('nombre_grain.csv',delimiter=',')
phi0ex1=211*[zeros(shape(251*251))]
gr1=zeros(shape=(251,251))
for k in range(0,len(ngrains)):
for i,j in enumerate(data1):
    for s in range(0,251):
        gr1[i]=where(s==ngrains[k],1,0)
phi0ex1[k]=gr1
print phi0ex1
```

#

Comment: You need to indent the body of the first loop.

Comment: This question is unclear, can you clarify what you want a bit more thoroughly?

Comment: i have a list  that contains 210 diffrent value that i load through "ngrains" file. then an other file "data" contains 250*250 elements, i want to look at each element of "data" see if it's equal to first element of "ngrains" if so replace it by one if not put zero instead. then the array of 250*250 that i get containing eather zeros or ones  i want to put it in an other list of arrays (phi0ex). and so on with all values in "ngrains"
i hope i explained it well, thanks

Comment: i found the solution thank you guys for showing intrest, accully the function where() do the iteration it self (that i did'nt know) there is no need to put it in an other loop, only the loop over "ngrains will do the trick".

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution thank you guys for showing intrest, accully the function where() do the iteration it self (that i did'nt know) there is no need to put it in an other loop, only the loop over "ngrains will do the trick.

```
data=loadtxt('data.csv',delimiter=',')
data1=data.transpose()
ngrains=loadtxt('nombre_grain.csv',delimiter=',')
phi0ex=len(ngrains)*[zeros(shape(250))]

for k in range(len(ngrains)):
    print ngrains[k]    
    phi0ex[k]=where(data1==ngrains[k],1,0)

print phi0ex
```